# date Date variable

Tags: mysql, sql, date

An error appears in the 'exams' table, because of the date Date variable - I've searched nearly everywhere (using Google) for an answer.

```
Drop table if exists exams;
CREATE TABLE administration2.exams (
date DATE,
censor VARCHAR(45) ,
idstudents VARCHAR(11),
idcourses VARCHAR(11),
grade INT (11),
PRIMARY KEY (date,censor));

insert into exams(date, censor, idstudents, idcourses, grade)
('2013-11-06', 'Ole Pedersen','201210066', 'dDB', 7),
```

Here is the problem ('2013-11-06') - it says:

> `syntax_error, UNEXPECTED TEXT_STRING, expecting SELECT_SYM.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `values` statement:

```
insert into exams(date, censor, idstudents, idcourses, grade)
    values ('2013-11-06', 'Ole Pedersen','201210066', 'dDB', 7);
```

You can also do this with `select`, if you drop the parentheses:

```
insert into exams(date, censor, idstudents, idcourses, grade)
    select '2013-11-06', 'Ole Pedersen','201210066', 'dDB', 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and small

```
insert into exams
    select '2013-11-06', 'Ole Pedersen','201210066', 'dDB', 7 from exams
```

OR

```
insert into exams
    values ('2013-11-06', 'Ole Pedersen','201210066', 'dDB', 7);
```

Comment: Awesome one dude! ;) Cheers alot!